# A correct English expression for heavy and aching head

Tags: expressions, translation

There is a Russian expression referring to the feeling of heaviness and pain in the head that translates literally as "head is buzzing" or "head is humming" (голова гудит). Is there any similar English expression?

I saw an expression "brain buzz", but it seems to have a completely different meaning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Throbbing head***

Throbbing:

> Feel pain in a series of regular beats: "her foot throbbed with pain";
>   "a throbbing headache"

Comment: Seems close to me. Would it be correct to use a simile "her head throbbed like (something that throbs)" then?

Comment: @Avenger911  You could do, if you wanted to. But the adjective, throbbing, is quite effective used by itself and is often used to describe a pulsating, constant pain in many different parts of the body.

Answer (score 0):

"I have a migraine" is commonly used. "Migraine" is a specific medical condition, but people use it figuratively to mean their head is so overloaded it hurts.

Answer (score 0):

I say that I *have a head like a pumpkin*, from the sensation of swelling and feeling (more than usually) stupid. But I can't find any references to support this usage.